# Oozie SparkAction failing

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

On HDP 2.3.4 I'm trying to test out Oozie's SparkAction.

The Spark (1.5.2) Application that I wrote is trivial and solely for testing out Oozie (4.2.0):

```
val tbl = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tbl")
val count = tbl.count   
log.info(s"The table has ${count} records.")
```

This application works when using `spark-submit`, both in YARN-Client and YARN-Cluster modes.

My `job.properties` and `workflow.xml` files are as follows:

**job.properties**

```
nameNode=hdfs://myhost.com:8020
jobTracker=myhost.com:8032
queueName=default
projectRoot=user/${user.name}/workflows/sparkaction-test

master=yarn-cluster
mode=cluster
class=com.myCompany.SparkActionTest
hiveSite=hive-site.xml
jars=${nameNode}/${projectRoot}/lib/sparkaction-test_2.10-1.0.jar


oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/${projectRoot}
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://myhost.com:18080/
spark.eventLog.dir=${nameNode}/user/spark/applicationHistory
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
```

**workflow.xml**

```
<workflow-app name="spark-test-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="spark-test"/>
    <action name="spark-test">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <mode>${mode}</mode>
            <name>Testing Spark Action</name>
            <class>${class}</class>
        <jar>${jars}</jar>
            <spark-opts>--files ${hiveSite}</spark-opts>
         </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="errorcleanup" />
    </action>

    <kill name="errorcleanup">
      <message>Spark Test WF failed. [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name ="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I cleaned out the Oozie sharelib for Spark (moved them into a different directory) and left only the following jars in them:

```
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
oozie-sharelib-spark-4.2.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar
spark-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-yarn-shuffle.jar
spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar
spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar
```

Unfortunately, the Oozie workflow fails with the following error message:

The workflow is killed after being in running status for about 20 minutes and the error message is as follows: **Call From host.xxx.com/x.x.x.x to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused**

I can ping 0.0.0.0 but can't telnet port 8032.

Comment: Could you please list the wat are the jars used for SPARK in the HDFS,Share-lib locaiton.? may be problem with adding spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoopx.x.x in Share lib.

Comment: @karthik I copied all of the jars from the spark lib into the Oozie Sharelib. However, our HDP got corrupted and needed to be reformatted so I'm working on a newer version of HDP (2.3.4). I'm no longer running into the issues previously but now a different error. Please see my update above.

Comment: In that jobTracker you specified port as 8050 is that listening to resourcemanager ? 
for the other hand solution ,
problem might be upgrading the sharelib packages seem to be version mismatch. By default oozie will perform "SPARK-SUBMIT".  or Tachyon jar required for above sample.

Comment: @karthik yes, the jobTracker I defined matches the yarn.resourcemanager.address found in yarn-site.xml, so I'm not quite sure why the logs show it's trying to connect to port 8032. As for the sharelib packages, how would I be able to check for version mismatches? I did make sure though that when I built the app with sbt I marked the spark dependencies as "provided" in `build.sbt` and used the same Scala version. As for the tachyon jars, I do see `tachyon-0.5.0.jar` and `tachyon-client-0.5.0.jar` in the sharelib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by changing the resource manager port (`yarn.resourcemanager.address` in advanced yarn-site settings in Ambari YARN configs) from 8050 (Hortonworks default) to 8032. It seems Oozie only works on port 8032 for SparkAction

Comment: I am trying implement as you mentioned in your question but I am facing different error.`JA008: File does not exist: hdfs://{namenodehost}:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20160622120957/spark/jets3t-0.7.1.jar`. I removed all default  spark shared lib jars as you mentioned and moved spark lib into the Oozie Sharelib. This is urgent need for me. could you help in this regards.

Comment: I restarted yarn, now I am getting different error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain not found`